# MatButton - How to modify overlay style when clicking

Tags: angular, angular-material2

I'm trying to apply custom style to MatButton. I applied some border-radius on .mat-button class. However when I click on the button, the overlay (with ripple effects) remains the same (without inheriting border-radius)

I tried to apply style to .mat-button-focus-overlay, .mat-button-ripple, .mat-ripple (both `border-radius: inherit | 10px` and it doesn't have any effect (event with `!important` flag).

Since this ripple is JS generated : does anyone has an idea of how can I style it the right way ? (e.g: Material theming etc)

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I usually do when work with Angular Material and want to change default styles: inspect the `button` element in devtools (it should contain some child elements), and try to change style for every element (then don't forget to remove unnecessary styles you wrote), move from parent to child. It always works fine for me. Sometimes you will also need to use `::ng-deep` for your goal.

*However when I click on the button, the overlay (with ripple effects) remains the same (without inheriting border-radius)*

If you use the latest Material version, the element you are looking for is:

```
<div class="mat-button-ripple mat-ripple" matripple=""></div>
```

I tried to change `border-radius` for it on Angular Material website (in devtools), and it works fine without `!important`.

Comment: `::ng-deep .mat-button-ripple { border-radius: inherit }` works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the same problem with z-index.
Something like this:

```
.mat-button, .mat-flat-button {
    border-radius: 18px !important;

    .mat-button-ripple {
      border-radius: inherit;
      z-index: 1;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you should not try to change a library that much to suit your needs.

Instead, you should create your own button. You can find examples around the Internet, **[such as there](https://codepen.io/Craigtut/pen/dIfzv)**.

You can then style your newly created component to cope with your design and theming. If you don't know how to do that, you can find **[more information here](https://material.angular.io/guide/theming-your-components)**

```
// Mandatory codepen code
```